# Prove that $10 \times 10$ grid filled with positive integers contains two elements sharing a side such that their difference is at least $6$.

Tags: combinatorics

I have a $10 \times 10$ grid filled with different positive integers and want to prove that some two numbers sharing a side in a grid differ by at least $6$.

My solution is: Let $m$ be the smallest and $M$ the greatest integer from the grid, then $M - m \ge 99$ (because every number in the grid is different). Consider the shortest path from $m$ to $M$. It consists of at most $19$ numbers (including $M$ and $m$). Let $x_1, x_2, ... x_k$ be the numbers on the path. Assuming that $|x_i - x_{i + 1}| \le 5$ we have $|M - m| = |x_1 - x_2| + ... + |x_{k - 1} - x_k| \le 5 * 18 = 90 < 99$, hence contradiction.

It isn't very nice or clever or the one I would come up with quickly solution. Can you think of anything better? Maybe easier or shorter one?

Comment: That's already a sleek pigeonhole-based solution!

Comment: Why, then, would you want a better answer if there isn't one?

Comment: I would say it is hard to find a better solution than the one you gave.